# Is it true that Amy is the Doctor's mother in law in two different ways?

Tags: doctor-who

I get that he married River Song and Amy is her mother but the Tenth Doctor married Liz 1, who is the daughter of Henry 8, didn't Amy accidently marry Henry 8? Does that make her his mother in law again?

Comment: Point of order: "in-law" status isn't commutative. My wife's sister is my sister-in-law, but her husband wouldn't be my brother-in-law... only a man married to my sister could be such. If it's commutative, then everyone in the world is everyone else's in-law one way or another.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### Yes.

Amy is the Doctor's mother-in-law because [he married her daughter](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/The_Wedding_of_River_Song_(TV_story)) (River Song, by Rory and TARDIS), and she is his stepmother-in-law because [she married his other father-in-law](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/The_Power_of_Three_(TV_story)) (Henry VIII, father of Elizabeth I whom [the Doctor also married](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/The_Day_of_the_Doctor_(TV_story))).

Whether or not this means the Doctor or Amy or both are bigamists is a matter we leave as an exercise for the fandom. (Moffat, please stop making off-hand jokes with awful implications.)

Comment: Moffat, please don't.

Comment: Can we have books/episodes where the weddings took place? I don't remember Henry VIII?

Comment: @Liath Does that edit help? You don't remember Henry VIII because that marriage is the off-hand joke I refer to.

Comment: @BESW it's a real shame SE doesn't let you double upvote...